# How to tell python csv reader to consider data of 8th row as header of data frame

Tags: python, csv, dataframe

I have csv file with below data, I want to import only 5th,8th & 9th row and assign 8th row data as data frame column header.

CSV file:

```
Variable Name            V1 G1  h2  K34
Variable Category        V2 G2  h3  K35
Variable Description     V3 G3  h4  K36
Variable Decomposition   V4 G4  h5  K37
Variable Unit            V5 G5  h6  K38
Methodological Notes     V6 G6  h7  K39
Sources                  V7 G7  h8  K40
Variable Code            A1 A2  A3  A4
data                     V9 G9  h10 K42
```

Output:

```
Variable Code   A1  A2  A3  A4
Variable Unit   V5  G5  h6  K38
data            V9  G9  h10 K42
```

My Code:

```
data = pd.read_csv('D:\Sunil_Work\temp8\temp\WID_AM_MacroData.csv',sep=';').loc[[4,7,8]]
```

Comment: Where does `;` actually appear to be a separator in your example?

Answer (score 0):

After that, you can assign header by

```
data.columns = data.loc[0]
```

Comment: thanks..., can we update column name while importing itself? bcz some column has blank values...